# Understanding Redux Thunk Typescript Generics and Types

Tags: typescript, redux, redux-thunk

I'm a little confused about the syntax of Redux Thunk in Typescript. I'm fairly new to Typescript but have an ok grasp of it, but there is a particular part that I don't understand.

Here is the type definition file for redux-thunk:

```
import { Middleware, Action, AnyAction } from "redux";

export interface ThunkDispatch<S, E, A extends Action> {
  <T extends A>(action: T): T; // I don't understand this line
  <R>(asyncAction: ThunkAction<R, S, E, A>): R; // or this line
}

export type ThunkAction<R, S, E, A extends Action> = (
  dispatch: ThunkDispatch<S, E, A>,
  getState: () => S,
  extraArgument: E
) => R;

export type ThunkMiddleware<S = {}, A extends Action = AnyAction, E = undefined> = Middleware<ThunkDispatch<S, E, A>, S, ThunkDispatch<S, E, A>>;

declare const thunk: ThunkMiddleware & {
  withExtraArgument<E>(extraArgument: E): ThunkMiddleware<{}, AnyAction, E>
}

export default thunk;
```

The part that I'm confused by is:

```
<T extends A>(action: T): T; // I don't understand this line
<R>(asyncAction: ThunkAction<R, S, E, A>): R; // or this line
```

I've looked at the documentation and it shows this:

```
interface GenericIdentityFn<T> {
    (arg: T): T;
}

function identity<T>(arg: T): T {
    return arg;
}

let myIdentity: GenericIdentityFn<number> = identity;
```

Does this mean then that a ThunkDispatch is a function, and that it can follow either of those two function signatures?

I can see from the Thunk Action that dispatch will always be a ThunkDispatch, but it's the ThunkDispatch interface that I can't make out.

It would be fantastic if someone could explain this for me.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, `store.dispatch(action)` returns the dispatched action object.

The line `<T extends A>(action: T): T;` is describing that behavior:

- We dispatch an action object, and the type of the object is `T`
- The return value of dispatch is that same object

Similarly, for `<R>(asyncAction: ThunkAction<R, S, E, A>): R`:

- `R` is the generic parameter for the return type of a particular thunk
- When we dispatch that thunk, `dispatch(thunk())` returns the result of the thunk

And yes, that syntax is saying that `ThunkDispatch` is a function with two different overloads.

Comment: Thanks Mark - so the two lines specify the non-async and async variants of the dispatch function?

Comment: Sort of. Thunks aren't actually asynchronous in and of themselves - [that's a question about what logic you've written inside](https://gist.github.com/markerikson/ea4d0a6ce56ee479fe8b356e099f857e). The typings are specifying the difference between passing a plain action object to `dispatch`, and passing a thunk function (regardless of whether the work that thunk does is sync or async).

Comment: Thanks Mark - so the first line is saying you can mark a normal action creator as a ThunkDispatch (passing in a plain object) and the second is saying you can pass in a Thunk function? Thank you again for clarifying this

Comment: No. Normally, `dispatch` can _only_ accept plain action objects. That `ThunkDispatch` type is saying that now, `dispatch` can accept plain action objects _or_ thunk functions.